# Wordpress Query - Blog Cards Duplicate issue

Tags: php

My Blog Cards are duplicating every three cards. How can I solve this?

```
<div class="blog-container-ehukuk">                                                 
                                <?php
                                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                                $args = array(
                                        'post_type'=> 'post',
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                                        'order' => 'DESC',
                                        'orderby' => 'date',
                                        'paged' => $paged
                                        );
                                $result = new WP_Query( $args );
                                ?>
                                
                                <?php if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
                            
    

        <div class="container-fostrap">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" alt="card__image" class="card__image" width="100%">

                            <div class="card-content">
                                <h4 class="card-title">
                                    <a href="http://www.fostrap.com/2016/03/bootstrap-3-carousel-fade-effect.html"> Bootstrap 3 Carousel FadeIn Out Effect
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p class="">
                                    Tutorial to make a carousel bootstrap by adding more wonderful effect fadein ...
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-read-more">
                                <a href="http://www.fostrap.com/2016/03/bootstrap-3-carousel-fade-effect.html" class="btn btn-link btn-block">
                                    Read More
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" alt="card__image" class="card__image" width="100%">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <h4 class="card-title">
                                    <a href="http://www.fostrap.com/2016/02/awesome-material-design-responsive-menu.html"> Material Design Responsive Menu
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p class="">
                                    Material Design is a visual programming language made by Google. Language programming...
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-read-more">
                                <a href="https://codepen.io/wisnust10/full/ZWERZK/" class="btn btn-link btn-block">
                                    Read More
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" alt="card__image" class="card__image" width="100%">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <h4 class="card-title">
                                    <a href="http://www.fostrap.com/2016/03/5-button-hover-animation-effects-css3.html">5  Button Hover Animation Effects
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p class="">
                                    tutorials button hover animation, although very much a hover button is very beauti...
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-read-more">
                                <a href="http://www.fostrap.com/2016/03/5-button-hover-animation-effects-css3.html" class="btn btn-link btn-block">
                                    Read More
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                                            
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                            
                </div>
```

Comment: have you considered using `pre_get_posts` to change the main query rather than creating new additional queries that slow your site down? This also fixes a lot of pagination issues

Comment: also inside the loop instead of displaying the current post, you have code to display the current post duplicated three times, you can't put the wrapper div elements inside the loop, and you can only display a post once inside the loop or you'll get multiple copies

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. So I have to add three loops? Also, I don't know about the pre_get_posts query. Is there a link I can check out?

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner, sorry. I'm guessing you are saying adding a function to functions.php and calling it. Instead of creating a new query every time.

Comment: you have a loop, and every time the loop runs and executes it prints the entire HTML, not just the individual post. Your HTML contains 3 divs not 1, so it gets displayed 3 times. Instead do it only once, and move the containing wrapper div's outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments [Tom J Nowell](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) already identified + solved the issue

Bellow I put code of it, and put functions that call post title, excerpt , permalink instead of static data given in question

```
<div class="blog-container-ehukuk">
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
            'post_type'=> 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'paged' => $paged
        );
    $result = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php
    if ( $result-> have_posts() ) {

        ?>
        <!-- Wrapper Divs -->
        <!-- One time -->
        <div class="container-fostrap">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">

                        <?php
                        while ( $result->have_posts() ) {

                            $result->the_post(); ?>

                            <!-- Repeater Div that has post data in it-->
                            <!-- Multiple times -->
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="card">
        
                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" alt="card__image" class="card__image" width="100%">

                                    <div class="card-content">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>">
                                                <?php echo get_the_title();?>
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p class="">
                                            <?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-read-more">
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>" class="btn btn-link btn-block">
                                            Read More
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Repeater Div END -->

                            <?php
                        } ?>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Wrapper Divs END -->

        <?php
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I already know how to do it with a single <div>. That works fine. I wondered how I could do it for multiple <div>'s. There was a blog post theme I wanted to use which has right side image on one and left side image on the other which repeats.

Comment: In theory, I need to make 2 loops and use do_not_repeat_id or something.